# Enable fullscreen on youtube iframe video

Tags: javascript, youtube

I create iframe youtube vidéo with this code:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// ...

_yt_player = new YT.Player("#myobjectytiframe", {
  height  : 640,
  width   : 480,
  videoId : video_id,
  events  : {
    'onReady': function(){
        _yt_player.playVideo();
        // ENABLE FULLSCREEN
    },
    'onStateChange': function(){},
    'onError': function(){}
  }
});
```

I would like to enable fullscreen in `onReady` callback, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

try using the html5 api:

```
document.fullScreen;
 node.requestFullScreen();
 document.cancelFullScreen();
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit ?